# Definitions of "Result" and "Codename" given on completion of Metal Gear Solid: Portable Ops

Tags: metal-gear-solid

Can anyone tell me where I can find definitions of the various "Result" and "Codename" values given on completion of **Metal Gear Solid: Portable Ops** for PSP?

On completing the game last night, I was given the result "Alpha" and the codename "Kerotan", but I have absolutely no idea if they are good, bad or just plain ugly.

Comment: Wow, the silence is deafening.

Comment: Hell, I'd settle for a URL to a reference in Japanese at this point...

Comment: http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Codename_(gameplay)#Metal_Gear_Solid:_Portable_Ops

Comment: @kotekzot: Why not make it a real answer and claim your prize?

Comment: I suppose a partial answer is better than no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Codename_(gameplay)#Metal_Gear_Solid:_Portable_Ops

[image]